# Stata 13 - Errors simulating confidence intervals when indexing on cut points

Tags: stata

I'm finalizing a short research note and having difficulty with my code in Stata 13.

I am estimating the effect of several variables on an ordinal dependent variable. I've run the initial estimation using ordered probit and generated predicted probabilities. For the purpose of this research note, I am required to generate confidence intervals for the predicted probabilities by hand (using simulation). Unfortunately, `margins` is not in my immediate future.

I've been trying to run the simulation but whenever I include the index function `[`i']` for each cut point of the dependent variable, I receive the error:

```
equation cut1][1 not found
```

The code I am using is:

```
set seed 23
mat b = e(b)
mat V = e(V)
drawnorm b_term b_pres b_acc cut1 cut2 cut3 cut4 cut5 cut6, mean(b) cov(V) n(1000) clear

gen p_1a_mean = .
forvalues i = 1/1000 {
    gen p_1a_`i' = normal(_b[/cut1][`i'] - (term*b_term[`i'] + pres*b_pres[`i'] + acc*b_acc[`i']))
    summarize p_1a_`i', meanonly
    replace p_1a_mean = r(mean) in `i'
}

drop p_1a_1-p_1a_1000
```

I find that when I do not index the cutpoint, I am able to run the code perfectly. This is strange, because I was let to believe that failing to index the cutpoint will bias the results.

Does anyone have any insight as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This is an international forum, so goodness knows how many people what UMD is. It doesn't matter for the question, however.

Comment: Hey Nick, absolutely. I just wanted to give credit where credit was due, so that it didn't look like I came up with this on my own!

Comment: A side-comment is that generating 1000 new variables here is quite unnecessary. You just need to initialise a single `p_la` outside the loop and `replace` it with new simulation results inside the loop.

Comment: Hi Nick - that's pretty interesting; I didn't know that you could do that. I was given this code and told to use it, so I didn't want to deviate from the assignment, but in future attempts, I will try your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show all your code but you are evidently fitting an ordered probit upstream. Consider the simplest kind of example:

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. oprobit rep78 weight

[stuff omitted]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       rep78 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |  -.0005881   .0001729    -3.40   0.001     -.000927   -.0002492
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       /cut1 |  -3.797833   .6421343                     -5.056393   -2.539273
       /cut2 |  -2.954918   .5957484                     -4.122563   -1.787272
       /cut3 |  -1.582673   .5471056                      -2.65498   -.5103658
       /cut4 |  -.6635675   .5192685                     -1.681315      .35418
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. di _b[/cut1]
-3.7978328
```

The coefficient you are using is a single estimate. It isn't to be subscripted and there are certainly aren't one thousand members of the same family, as your subscripting implies.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you so much for your help here. I'm sure you've guessed, but I'm still relatively new to maximum likelihood. I'll have to bone up on exactly what subscripting is. As it has been taught to me, running the simulation to generate confidence intervals around predicted probabilities requires running 1000 repetitions of the simulator. I am able to get the simulation to run wonderfully (and accurately) without the index function on the cut point([`i']), but not with it :/

Comment: Your comment just seems to repeat the question. Did you understand my answer? What you call the "index function" (there is one, but it's quite different) is just subscripting and not a function at all. `help subscripting`.

Comment: Hey Nick, I appreciate your help. I don't fully understand the index or subscripting concepts here. As I said, I'm still pretty new to both MLE and Stata. It looks like what you're saying that [`i'] is actually subscripting. I'll check out exactly what that means. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you like Nick's answer than officially Accept it.

Comment: You have been migrated to SO, but the focus here is on questions from professional or enthusiast programmers. So, the assumption is that you are writing code yourself and thus that you have studied the language. If you are at learner stage, you would be better off on Statalist, but there is the same presumption that you have tried to learn enough of the language for your needs.

Comment: Hey Nick, I had originally posted this to the CrossValidated section (which focuses on statistics), and it was redirected here. Thank you so much for all of your help - I really do appreciate it!